# week days sorting based on starting day

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, get-posts, sort

I have a taxonomy with weekdays.
I want them sorted based on basis of starting day opted by the user.
Basically, I am working on Timetable and different regions have different starting day of week.
What I want to do is sort my posts on the basis of

1. starting day of week e.g if i select saturday to be starting day, then i should get posts from saturday through friday.
2. Order By time

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to group by weekday, you can use `date("w", $date)` to have the weekday (http://php.net/date). after that you can sort by weekdays.

Comment: Are you doing this in a template file where you can simply run multiple queries, or are you doing this on an archive page where you'd want to manipulate the main query in some way?

Comment: @janh, I am doing it through plugin shortcode as well as a page template